# AngularJS ng-options, working with key value pairs in <select>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have been trying to work with an object I am retrieving through an $http call and using to populate drop-down boxes.

My object looks like this:

```
{1: Item1
↵L", 2: "Item2
↵", 3: "Item3
↵"}
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.data = {};
$http.get(baseUrl + "/Lookup/Get?param=Ref_myModel").success(function (result) {

    $scope.data.myModel = result

})
.error(function (error) {
    $scope.data.error = error;
});
```

Finally in HTML:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="MonStatus" ng-model="data.myModel" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in data.myModel"></select>
```

The select drop-down is populated with values from the model with no issue but as soon as the user selects a value, the value is replaced by the key. I have been reading through the documentation trying to understand ng-options however I am having some issues since all of the examples are using objects with proper key, value formats while I have a key and text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using $scope.data.myModel as your model and the source element for your options. These should be separate:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.myModel = '';
$http.get(baseUrl + "/Lookup/Get?param=Ref_myModel").success(function (result) {

    $scope.data.options = result

})
.error(function (error) {
    $scope.data.error = error;
});
```

Then in your view:

```
<select class="form-control" id="MonStatus"
    ng-model="data.myModel" 
    ng-options="key as value for  (key , value) in data.options"></select>
```

This will bind the selection to myModel and let the options remain what they were...

Some extra advice:

Also, don't do $http calls in your controllers, place them in a service. Always avoid logic as much as possible in your controllers and let services/factories take care of the heavy lifting. Also, it's a pretty good idea to place `data-` before `ng-*` attributes.

Comment: This works and makes perfect sense with not binding the populated model. However , the model that's used is now empty. So when do we use a populated model? Like in the example here mycolors has a value: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select. Also, I plan on moving the http calls from the controller into factories and refactoring to use the resolve property in the routeprovider after I get all of the calls set up.

Comment: you would pre-populate the model if you want your form to load-up pre-populated...so in your success callback (btw, another tip, I believe `.success` & `.error` are deprecated in favor of `.then`) you could assign `$scope.data.myModel = $scope.data.options[1]` if you want to set the model to preset to the 2nd item.